# Unable to install tensorflow=1.0.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to install tensorflow 1.0.0 on windows 10 , but, it's showing this error message:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.0 (from versions ...
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.0
```

[image]

I have already tried to install using anaconda v 5.2, Python v 3.6

Comment: Tensorflow 1.0.0 is a very old version. Why do you need to install that? It's probably so old it's no longer on pip and you'll have to download and install the file manually.

Comment: Tensorflow on Windows is somewhat limited and only supports specific Python versions. E.g. [Tensorflow 1.1 is only for Python 3.5.x](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/install/install_windows). Seeing this, it's doubtful that an earlier TF version (1.0) is available for a later Python version (3.6).

Comment: If you really want version 1.0 you could install from source. (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.0.0)

Answer (score 6):

Try by creating python 3.5 env in anaconda it should work.

```
conda create --name tf1.0 pip python=3.5
activate tf1.0
pip install tensorflow==1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Then after much hardships, I got to know that anaconda versions>=4.2.0 don't support the direct installation of tensorflow version 1.0.0, So, I installed anaconda version=4.2.0 and works perfectly now.
it takes direct installation:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.0.0
```